Proper way to compute information gain in a decision tree when tests have pre-requisites
I want to build a decision tree and ID3 (greedy information gain maximization) seems fine, but when picking which test to perform at a node, some tests can only be done after some other tests.
Here's a motivating example:
Please imagine that I need to generate a decision tree to test a string that I know a priori is one of the following†:

"foo"
"food"
"fool"
"foot"

† - I know perfect hashing is better than dtrees for closed sets of strings. This is just an example
The features I can test might be:

a bunch of range comparisons on the first character
a bunch of range comparisons on the second character
a bunch of range comparisons on the third character
whether the length is > 3
a bunch of range comparisons on the fourth character

Testing the fourth character without first checking that the length is > 3 might result in an out of bounds read, so the length check (4) is a pre-requisite for (5).
Are there principled ways to incorporate the fact that (4) unlocks (5) into the ID3 evaluation of (4) or is there a better algorithm for this?

ID3 already does what you want.  It chooses a decision rule for the root node, by considering all candidate features and choosing the "best".  All you need to do is filter the set of features to only consider those that are valid (for instance, (5) would not be valid at the root node, so it would not be among the set considered for the decision at the root).  ID3 chooses the best decision rule at the root node, then recursively builds each subtree.  If (4) is chosen in the root node, then (5) would be valid at its children and would thus be among the features that are considered by ID3.

I could, but I'd like the decision to use a pre-requisite to, in part, be based on the post-requisites it enables for subsequent tree layers.

@MikeSamuel, I'm afraid that requirement is unclear.  It's not clear to me exactly what solutions would or wouldn't suffice.  I suspect that is a XY problem; that it's not the real requirement -- that the reason you want to use that information is you hope it will help improve the algorithm by some other metric, and if so, then I think your problem statement should be based on measuring that ultimate metric, rather than based on how the algorithm goes about achieving that metric.

Also it doesn't make sense to me.  ID3 is by design a greedy algorithm that makes the locally optimal choice -- it doesn't plan ahead. If you want solutions that plan ahead or seek a globally optimal choice, ID3 is unlikely to be the right starting point.  But an empirical observation is that ID3 is often close to globally optimum, so it's a pragmatic choice.
